# Add Timestamp to Trace.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, debugging, timestamp, trace

In my C# .NET application I have an issue with the Trace.WriteLine()-method. I uses this method alot, and want to add a TimeStamp every time I use it.

Instead of Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Something wrong!"), is there a solution where the DateTime is on default?

Comment: You can use [Essential Diagnostics](http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/) just [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11361706/1353187)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your own "`TraceLine(string msg)`" method and start calling that:

```
void TraceLine(string msg, bool OmitDate)
{
    if (!OmitDate)
        msg = DateTime.Now + " " + msg;
    Trace.WriteLine(msg);
}

void TraceLine(string msg) {TraceLine(msg, false);}
```

Comment: These should be static methods, as no dependency on the object calling them.

Comment: I'd suggest logging with UTC timestamps to avoid any ambiguity in timezones etc. - also you might want to use Format or StringBuilder to avoid all those temporary strings

Comment: actually, the most efficient string concatenation method is probably string.Concat(). Not that it would matter anyway.

Answer (score 102):

## Via code

You can configure the TraceOutputOptions flags enum.

```
var listener = new ConsoleTraceListener() { TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.Timestamp | TraceOptions.Callstack };
Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);

Trace.TraceInformation("hello world");
```

This does not work for Write and WriteLine, you have use the TraceXXX methods.

## Via app.config

This can also be configured in your App.config with a somewhat equivalent and using TraceSource:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <sources>
        <source name="TraceSourceApp">
          <listeners>
            <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp" />
          </listeners>
        </source>
      </sources>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And in code you can:

```
private static TraceSource mySource =   
        new TraceSource("TraceSourceApp");
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  mySource.TraceInformation("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Config file equivalent: traceOutputOptions = "DateTime, Timestamp" to the system.diagnostics/sources/listeners/add tag. Save an  [MSDN lookup - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c(v=vs.110).aspx), and it is mentioned in one of the other answers here. Somehow ended up seeing the MSDN one before the other answer.

Comment: Note that the trace output options do not apply to Trace.WriteLine, only Trace.TraceInformation / Trace.Trace* methods.

Answer (score 20):

You can set the `app.config` file to use a timestamp (relative and current time) for all trace listeners using the `traceOutputOptions`

```
traceOutputOptions = "DateTime, Timestamp";
```

Comment: As per one of the more popular answers, this is only effective when the TraceXXX methods are used.

Comment: This is the approach when using the trace listeners  
        <listeners>
          <add name="fileTrace"  traceOutputOptions = "DateTime, Timestamp" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.log" />
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper method that did it:

```
public static void DoTrace(string message)
{
    DoTrace(message,true);
}

public static void DoTrace(string message, bool includeDate)
{
    if (includeDate) {
        Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + message);
    } else {
        Trace.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because DoTrace is static and you don't have access to Trace. You could use HttpContext.Current.Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + message)

Comment: Isn't System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine() also static? Depends which he's using I guess :/

Answer (score 0):

We use log4net TraceAppender where you can config layout or filtering easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `TextWriterTraceListener`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1171670/806690).