# .NET 4.0 Tracing; Problems using TraceSwitch

Tags: c#, .net, trace

I'm trying to set up .NET tracing in my C# application. I've managed to set up my application to trace into the console and a .log file. But I can't set up the `TraceSwitch` correctly.

I'm using the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class for tracing. I've read in this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822941/net-tracing-not-working-with-diagnostics-tracesource-only-diagnostics-trace)** that I should use `TraceSource` instead of `Diagnostics.Trace` for logging/tracing. Is there an easy way I can implement the "new way of tracing" (after .Net 2.0)? Or do I have to write my own Trace-class that uses `TraceSource` and provides functions like the "old trace (before 2.0)" - for e.g. `Trace.TraceInformation("my msg")`?

#### Here's my App.config file:

```
<!-- Trace Sources -->
<sources>
  <source name="MySource" switchName="AppTraceLevel"> <!-- switchValue="Off" does not work either -->
    <listeners>
      <add name="ConsoleTraceListener" />
      <add name="LogTraceListener" />
      <remove name="Default"  />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>

<!-- Trace Level -->
<switches>
  <add name="AppTraceLevel" value="Off"/>
</switches>

<!-- Trace Listeners -->
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="ConsoleTraceListener"
       type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"
       initializeData="false"
       traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
  <add name="LogTraceListener"
       type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="MyAppName.log" />
</sharedListeners>

<!-- Trace Options -->
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="ConsoleTraceListener" />
    <add name="LogTraceListener" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

Comment: If you want to avoid "unnecessary" parameters when tracing, you'll need a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hoped I could avoid that.