# How to Monitor HTTP Requests Directly From C# Server Console?

Tags: c#

does anyone know how to get a C# server application running in the console to display HTTP requests from a client as shown in this image?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC0k1.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer. It was actually log4net that made that output though but this is almost as good.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is spin up an HTTP server and write out requests to the console, it should be pretty easy to accomplish using [OWIN](http://owin.org/) and [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana). Just install the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener

And use something along the lines of the following:

```
public static class Program
{
    private const string Url = "http://localhost:8080/";

    public static void Main()
    {
        using (WebApp.Start(Url, ConfigureApplication))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening at {0}", Url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void ConfigureApplication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((ctx, next) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Request \"{0}\" from: {1}:{2}",
                ctx.Request.Path,
                ctx.Request.RemoteIpAddress,
                ctx.Request.RemotePort);

            return next();
        });
    }
}
```

You can of course tweak the output to your liking, having access to the full request and respose objects.

It will give you something like this:

[image: HTTP requests]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `System.Diagnostics Tracing` in `Web API`. On the asp.net website, you'll be able to read [a detailed article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Another possibility is turning on the IIS logging and then read the logfiles. I'm not quite sure how this is done, it's just what I do on apache2/linux, where you can `tail -f log`. I read something about powershell equivalents, but not for consoleapps, so I think I would stick with the Tracing.

**Edit:** After some looking around on SO I found this similar question with relevant answers:
[How do I see the raw HTTP request that the HttpWebRequest class sends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808016/how-do-i-see-the-raw-http-request-that-the-httpwebrequest-class-sends)