# Log Http Post request before calling

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api

Hi Want to log http Request before making the call. With all the values - for dev purposes. My code is below

```
   using (HttpClient hc = httpClient)
            {

                    hc.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint); 
                    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

**// Want to Log the request here that captures Header and body content**

                    HttpResponseMessage response = hc.PostAsJsonAsync(url, bodyKeyValues).Result;

            }
```

I am not to able to figure out how to get the HttpRequestobject. Is there a way to get the httpRequestObject as a whole?

Comment: Well, what is keeping you from doing it?

Comment: @PeterBons I am not sure how to get the httprequestmessage from httpclient. I generally log the responses as console.writeline(response.ReadAsStringAsync().Result) - but i am not sure how to get the whole request.

Comment: @NightMonger, Create a delegate handler and inject that into the hander to intercept the request before it is sent. You can do your logging there

Comment: There is built-in logging/tracing E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808016/how-do-i-see-the-raw-http-request-that-the-httpwebrequest-class-sends / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient