# How to see SOAP request data sent by C# ASP.NET app that gets sent over network?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a C# ASP.NET application that is sending a post request to a WSDL based SOAP client and I would like to see the body of that request.  The request is sent from the backend, not a browser.  Plot twist: I lack permissions to install any network traffic sniffing software.  What is a good way to see the XML being sent in the request?  I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: It depends on what triggers your C# ASP.NET application to send the request. What is the furthest step you can see the request? If you have the sources, you can debug it. If you have another application which does some action and that triggers the previously mentioned app to send the POST request, you can run separate instances of VS2010 and hit the breakpoint where you need (again, assuming you have all the sources for the applications mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the application?  If so, a couple thoughts:

1. Install [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) with a [SOAP plugin](https://github.com/jgreene/Glimpse.Soap).

or

2. Add some logging capability you can switch on/off via an [appSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx).  Use that to trigger dumping it to a log file/database
   table.  If you're already using [Elmah](https://elmah.github.io/) you can piggy-back off it
   and [dump it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441062/how-to-use-elmah-to-manually-log-errors) there.

or

3. You mentioned you couldn't install Fiddler, but what about on a different PC?  Fiddler supports r[emote connections](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorRemoteMachine), so if you have it on another PC you could run it there and simply change the web.config in your app to use that as the [proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings).

Answer (score 0):

Can you install any software?  If so give [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) a try, it's an http debugging proxy that does not require admin rights to install.

Without installing any software [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808016/how-do-i-see-the-raw-http-request-that-the-httpwebrequest-class-sends) question, specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683524/93125) answer looks like it would do the trick.  It contains the configuration to enable the System.Net tracing mechanism in the web.config.

For an auto generated client from a service reference one of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net) question should work.  It's very similar to the answers above but specifically for a client generated from a service reference.

Comment: Good idea, but no, I cannot install any software.

Comment: what are you using to send the post?  A System.Net.WebRequest?

Comment: I'm communicating with the endpoint using a WSDL URL as a service reference.  Basically its a bunch of auto generated code that mediates the request/response cycle.