# HttpClient Consuming GitHub API - Basic Authentication Error 403 StatusCode

Tags: c#, basic-authentication, github-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a connection to a Github API endpoint using basic authentication. And no matter what I do, I'm getting 403 status as an answer. Has anyone ever experienced this ?

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    var basicAuthentication = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_username}:{_password}");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(basicAuthentication));

    var result = await client.GetAsync("https://api.github.com/user");
    var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Could someone help, please?

Comment: Try with postman first.  Find out if it's a C# issue or a request issue.

Comment: Hi, I do this request in postman an curl and i have the response.

Comment: Turn on tracing with [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683524/1563833) and see if your request matches the one you sent in postman.  If not, find the differences.

Comment: I don't think you need to `ToBase64String` the header value.  Is that it?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Wyck I found the solution:

I need increase this line: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("XXX", "1.0"));

after read github documentation api.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I was calling this URL (https://api.github.com/repos/thomasgalliker/PiWeatherStation/releases) in the browser and it worked well. When I use an HttpClient with a GET request, it fails with 403 Forbidden.

```
var response = await this.httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.github.com/repos/thomasgalliker/PiWeatherStation/releases");
```

Adding this line of code before issuing the GetStringAsync request resolved the issue (no idea why):

```
this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("request");
```